# How to get number of syllables of text while typing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React to build a web app and I want to find the number of syllables inside of a textarea while the user is typing.

I keep getting errors like "cannot find length of a null".

At this point all I want is to console.log() it.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class UserInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ""};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        console.log(calculateSyllables(event.target.value));
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert("A name was submitted: " + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    UserInput: 
                    <textarea rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="UserInput" 
                              value={this.state.value} 
                              onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

function calculateSyllables(word) {
    if (word != null) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        word = word.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '');
        word = word.replace(/^y/, '');
        return word.match(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g).length;
    } else {
        console.log("else");
        return 0;
    }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
    <UserInput />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the source documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> Return value
>
> An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found.

From your question, it can be perceived as the `.length` is being called on a null object in `handleChange(event) => calculateSyllables()`. Check if your argument is correct.

I have the following example:

```
const paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. It barked.';
const regex = /[aeiouy]{1,2}/g;
const found = paragraph
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '')
    .replace(/^y/, '')
    .match(regex)
    .length;
console.log(found); // expected output: 13
```

Working as intended.

And the same function, with argument `.` yields:

> Error: paragraph.replace(...).replace(...).match(...) is null

A fix could be:

```
let array = paragraph // <= This is your argument
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '')
    .replace(/^y/, '')
    .match(regex);
return Array.isArray(array) ? array.length : 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! That edit at the end did it for me. I just had to add the instantiation of regex.